# integer division, rounding

Tags: c, algorithm, division

There is integer variable, voltage in millivolts.

```
signed int voltage_mv = 134; //134mV
```

I have 2-segment display and I want to display hundredths of volts.

How can I convert milivolts to hundredths volts in one operation? Without IF statement, without function?

```
134 => 13
135 => 14
```

Comment: A short if statement can be made into a ternary operation, ?:.

Comment: 134 mV is 0.134 V, not 13 V. What are you trying to do, exactly ?

Comment: if you want to display a millivolt value in volts, you have to dividie it by 1000. Unless your value is than 1000 mV, the result will be 0 represented as an integer. Are you sure you want to display in Volts?

Comment: sorry about wrong description, I want to display hundredths of volts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about simple rounding:

```
int millivoltToDisplay (int millivolts)
{
  return (millivolts+5)/10;
}
```

(written as a function for clarity)

Comment: What if the input value is negative ? For correct rounding you need to test for this and subtract 5 rather than add 5, i.e. `return mv >= 0 ? (mv + 5) / 10 : (mv - 5) / 10;`

Comment: to Paul R. - great, thats it!

Answer (score 4):

For the same of completeness, if the denominator is odd, then instead of doing:

```
return (millivolts+denominator/2)/denominator;
```

you can just have

```
return (2*millivolts+denominator)/(2*denominator);
```

and get the correct rounding.