# signed integer division with rounding in C

Tags: c, signed, integer-division

I'd like to calculate x/y where x and y are both signed integers, and get a result rounded to the nearest integer.  Specifically, I'd like a function `rquotient(x, y)` using integer-only arithmetic such that:

```
ASSERT(rquotient(59, 4) == 15);
ASSERT(rquotient(59, -4) == -15);
ASSERT(rquotient(-59, 4) == -15);
ASSERT(rquotient(-59, -4) == 15);

ASSERT(rquotient(57, 4) == 14);
ASSERT(rquotient(57, -4) == -14);
ASSERT(rquotient(-57, 4) == -14);
ASSERT(rquotient(-57, -4) == 14);
```

I've looked to S.O. for a solution and found the following (each with their own shortcoming):

- [Rounding integer division (instead of truncating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/rounding-integer-division-instead-of-truncating) (round up only)
- [Integer division with rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917405/integer-division-with-rounding) (positive x and y only)
- [Round with integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950372/round-with-integer-division) (positive x and y only)
- [integer division, rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085239/integer-division-rounding) (positive y only, but a good suggestion in the comments)
- [Integer division rounding with negatives in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319880/integer-division-rounding-with-negatives-in-c) (question about the standard, not a solution)

Comment: This answer already has the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067292/2527795

Comment: @vll You are right!  I overlooked that answer since the OP was asking about rounding up, not rounding nearest.  So since it's not a duplicate, would you care to answer it here?

Answer (score 6):

If you know `x` and `y` both to be positive:

```
int rquotient_uu(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
  return (x + y/2) / y;
}
```

If you know `y` to be positive:

```
int rquotient_su(int x, unsigned int y) {
  if (x > 0) {
    return (x + y/2) / y;
  } else {
    return (x - y/2) / y;
  }
}
```

If both are signed:

```
int rquotient_ss(int x, int y) {
  if ((x ^ y) >= 0) {            // beware of operator precedence
    return (x + y/2) / y;        // signs match, positive quotient
  } else {
    return (x - y/2) / y;        // signs differ, negative quotient
  }
}
```

And if you really want to baffle your future self or are addicted to code golf, please resist the urge to write it this way: ;)

```
int rquotient_ss(int x, int y) {
  return (x + (((x^y)>=0)?y:-y)/2)/y;
}
```

Comment: Just beware of `int` overflow on some of those calculations.

Comment: Nice canonical.

Comment: To be pedantic, do `((unsigned)x^(unsigned)y)`.

Comment: It seems that `rquotient_ss` gives the [wrong result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wmUftW57mrhUXO79) (0) when x == y, though. I think the condition should be `(x ^ y) >= 0`

Comment: @Bob__ You are right!! I just stumbled across that myself in the unit tests!  Updating answer...

Comment: If the divisor is negative, invert both divisor and dividend.  If dividend is positive, compute `(int)(divisor/2u+dividend)/dividend`.  If negative, `-(int)(((divisor-1u)/2u+dividend)/dividend)`.  Note that this will avoid overflow except on weird systems where `unsigned` has one more padding bit than `int`.

Comment: @supercat: I like overflow avoidance, but your recipe seems wrong. For first quadrant (i.e. positive x and y), neither `quo = ((x/2) + y)/y` nor  `quo = (x/(2+y)/y` seem correct...

Comment: Oops.. The right hand of each expression should be the divisor.

Comment: @supercat: Um, not quite!  Write a test case for the O.P. and I'll be happy to incorporate your answer!

Comment: Let's see.  (divisor/2u+dividend)/divisor. For 7/5, that's (2+7)/5, which is 1 as it should be.  For 8/5, (2+8)/5==2.  For 8/6, (3+8)/6==1.  For 9/6, (3+9)/6==2.  For -(int)(((divisor-1u)/2u-dividend)/divisor), and -7/5, that's -((2+7)/5), which is -2.  For -8/5, -((2+8)/5)==-3.  For -9/6, -((2+9)/6) is -1 (rounding positive).  For -10/6, -((2+10)/6) is -2.  So I mistyped "/dividend" instead of "/divisor", and I added the negative divisor instead of either subtracting it or else explicitly adding the *magnitude* of it.

Comment: For even divisors, banker's rounding might sometimes be preferred to round-positive, but I regard the invariant that (n+d)/d==1+(n/d) [which holds for whole-numbers or real division] as more important than (-n)/d==-(n/d) [which holds for reals, but is meaningless for whole numbers].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207031/discussion-between-fearless-fool-and-supercat).

Comment: All the above solution exhibit problems for very large absolute values: `(x + y/2) / y` will overflow for `y > 1` and `x == UINT_MAX` or `x == INT_MAX` depending on signedness.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to use `round` and `double`:

```
#include <math.h>

int rquotient(int const x, int const y) {
    return (int)round((double)x / y);
}
```

Comment: Ah - In my mind I said "using integer only arithmetic" and forgot to specify that in the question (though I did add the tag "integer-division").  Forgive me, but I'll update the question.

Comment: @fearless_fool seems like a weird requirement. May I ask the reason for this strange requirement?

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable requirement, IMO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't come up with a situation under which you'd have that requirement. Is this a performance related thing?

Comment: @Ayxan: Two words: "Embedded Processors".  Most of my work uses tiny processors; dragging in a floating point library is a HUGE hit to available memory.

Comment: This also assumes `double` has enough precision to hold all `int` values without loss of precision.

Comment: Hey - since they original question didn't specify integer-only arithmetic (that constraint was added later), Ayxan's answer is reasonable.  I'm upvoting simply to counteract whoever downvoted...

Comment: @fearless_fool Since you said that I'll un-downvote.

Answer (score 2):

#### Timing suggested solutions

The code presented here tests the performance of the 3 suggested functions in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60009773/15168) by [fearless_fool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558639/fearless-fool) and the solution in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60009901/15168) by [Ayxan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10147399/ayxan).  The functions are modified to always take `int` arguments (the `const` in `int const x` is not needed), but the test code only uses test values in the range where both `x` and `y` are non-negative.

The code uses a set of timing functions available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `timer.c` and `timer.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
#define NDEBUG 1

#include "timer.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* JL: added static to rquotient_xx functions */

/* JL: removed two const qualifiers */
static
int rquotient_dd(int x, int y)
{
    return (int)round((double)x / y);
}

/* JL: removed unsigned - added assert */
static
int rquotient_uu(int x, int y)
{
    assert(x >= 0 && y > 0);
    return (x + y / 2) / y;
}

/* JL: removed unsigned - added assert */
static
int rquotient_su(int x, int y)
{
    assert(y > 0);
    if (x > 0)
        return (x + y / 2) / y;
    else
        return (x - y / 2) / y;
}

static
int rquotient_ss(int x, int y)
{
    if ((x ^ y) > 0)
        return (x + y / 2) / y;
    else
        return (x - y / 2) / y;
}

typedef int (*Divider)(int x, int y);

static void test_harness(const char *tag, Divider function)
{
    Clock clk;
    unsigned long long accumulator = 0;

    clk_init(&clk);

    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 1; i < INT_MAX / 1024; i += 13)
    {
        int max_div = i / 4;
        if (max_div == 0)
            max_div = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < max_div; j += 15)
            accumulator += (*function)(i, j);
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);

    char buffer[32];
    printf("%s: %10s  (%llu)\n", tag, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)), accumulator);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test_harness("rquotient_uu", rquotient_uu);
        test_harness("rquotient_su", rquotient_su);
        test_harness("rquotient_ss", rquotient_ss);
        test_harness("rquotient_dd", rquotient_dd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The use of `accumulator` serves two important purposes.  First, it checks that the different computations produce the same results.  Secondly, it ensures that the compiler cannot optimize the loops away — the accumulated value must be printed.  It is reassuring to see that the accumulated value is the same on all tests.  The oddball constants (`INT_MAX / 1024`, `13`, `15`) are guessed values that yield reasonable times on the test machine — they mean the tests cover quite a lot of values, without taking inappropriately long times.

#### Performance test results

I ran the tests on a MacBook Pro (15 inch, 2017 — with a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 chip and 16 GiB of 2133 Mhz LPDDR3 RAM) running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, compiled with (home-built) GCC 9.2.0 and the Xcode 11.3.1 toolchain.

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     iround53.c -o iround53 -L./lib -lsoq 
$
```

One set of timing results was:

```
rquotient_uu:   6.272698  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.257373  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.221263  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.956196  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.247602  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.289057  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.258776  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.878083  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.256511  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.286257  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.323997  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  11.055200  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.256689  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.302265  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.296409  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.943110  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.239497  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.238150  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.195744  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.975971  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.252275  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.218718  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.241050  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.986962  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.254244  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.213412  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.280628  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.963290  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.237975  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.278504  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.286199  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.984483  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.219504  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.208329  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.251772  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  10.983716  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.369181  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.362766  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.299449  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:  11.028050  (286795780245)
```

When analyzed, the mean and sample standard deviation for the different functions are:

```
Function       Count   Mean        Standard deviation
rquotient_uu      10    6.260618   0.040679 (sample)
rquotient_su      10    6.265483   0.048249 (sample)
rquotient_ss      10    6.265529   0.039216 (sample)
rquotient_dd      10   10.975506   0.047673 (sample)
```

It doesn't take much statistical knowledge to see that there is essentially no performance difference between the three 'all integer' functions, because the difference between the three means is much less than one standard deviation (and to be significant, it would need to be more than one standard deviation).  Nor does it take much skill to observe that converting to `double`, dividing, rounding, and converting back to integer takes almost twice as long as the all-integer versions.  In times (long) past, the integer vs floating-point discrepancy could have been a lot larger.  There is a modest amount of overhead in the loop calculations and accumulation; that would widen the disparity between the integer and floating-point computations.

The machine running the test had various programs open in the background, but there were no videos playing, the browser was showing Stack Overflow rather than advert-laden pages, and I was tinkering on a cell phone while the test ran on the laptop.  One attempted test run, during which I flicked between pages on the browser, showed much more erratic timing (longer times while I was using the browser, even though it is a multi-core machine).

Other tests with the condition `if ((x ^ y) > 0)` corrected to `if ((x ^ y) >= 0)` yielded slightly different timing results (but the same value for `accumulator`):

```
rquotient_su     10    6.272791    0.037206
rquotient_dd     10    9.396147    0.047195
rquotient_uu     10    6.293301    0.056585
rquotient_ss     10    6.271035    0.052786

rquotient_su     10    6.187112    0.131749
rquotient_dd     10    9.100924    0.064599
rquotient_uu     10    6.127121    0.092406
rquotient_ss     10    6.203070    0.219747

rquotient_su     10    6.171390    0.133949
rquotient_dd     10    9.195283    0.124936
rquotient_uu     10    6.214054    0.177490
rquotient_ss     10    6.166569    0.138124
```

The performance difference for the floating-point arithmetic is not quite so pronounced, but still definitively in favour of integer arithmetic.  The last of those tests, in particular, suggest there was some other activity on the machine while the tests were running — though that wasn't me looking at web pages or anything.

---

#### Using `-ffast-math`

[Ayxan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10147399/ayxan) asked:

> I wonder if `-ffast-math` would have made a difference.

I recompiled with the extra option, and it does indeed make a difference.  Note that the original code was compiled with `-O3` — it was optimized.  However, the raw data from a run with `-ffast-math` was:

```
rquotient_uu:   6.162182  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.068469  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.041566  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.568538  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.143200  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.071906  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.063543  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.543419  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.115283  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.083157  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.063975  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.536071  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.078680  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.072075  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.104850  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.585272  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.084941  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.080311  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.069046  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.563945  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.075380  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.236980  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.210127  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.787269  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.406603  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.378812  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.194098  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.589568  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.243652  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.132142  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.079181  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.595330  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.070584  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.081373  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.075867  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.558105  (286795780245)
rquotient_uu:   6.106258  (286795780245)
rquotient_su:   6.091108  (286795780245)
rquotient_ss:   6.128787  (286795780245)
rquotient_dd:   4.553061  (286795780245)
```

And the statistics from that are:

```
rquotient_su     10    6.129633    0.101331
rquotient_dd     10    4.588058    0.072669
rquotient_uu     10    6.148676    0.104937
rquotient_ss     10    6.103104    0.057498
```

It doesn't take a statistical genius to spot that this shows the `-ffast-math` floating-point alternative is now better than the integer version — by a similar factor to how integer was better than floating-point without the extra compiler option.

One more set of statistics with `-ffast-math`.  These show smaller variances (standard deviations), but the same overall result.

```
rquotient_su     10    6.060705    0.024372
rquotient_dd     10    4.543576    0.014742
rquotient_uu     10    6.057718    0.026419
rquotient_ss     10    6.061652    0.034652
```

For 32-bit integers, it would appear that with `-ffast-math`, the code using `double` can be faster than the code using only integers.

If the range was changed from 32-bit integers to 64-bit integers, then 64-bit doubles would not be able to represent all integer values exactly.  At that point, if the numbers being divided are large enough, you could start finding accuracy errors (the accumulator results might well be different).  A 64-bit double effectively has 53 bits to represent the mantissa, so if the number of bits in the integers were larger than that, accuracy drops.

---

## Performance testing is hard.  [YMMV!](https://acronymfinder.com/YMMV.html)

Indeed, it might be safer to say "Your Milage ***WILL*** Vary".

Comment: Great post! I wonder if `-ffast-math` would have made a difference.

Comment: Using `-ffast-math` makes a ***BIG*** difference, @Ayxan.

Comment: Excellent work!  Of course, on my target machine (a Cortex M0), there's no built-in floating point support, so it wouldn't be a fair comparison at all!

Comment: Thanks.  YMWV indeed!  And that's why I was fairly scrupulously careful to document where I was testing, because people on  other systems will have different results.  I am intrigued by the `-ffast-math` option — it improves things more than I'd expect.

Comment: Most of the above solution exhibit problems for very large absolute values: `(x + y/2) / y` will overflow for `y > 1` and `x == INT_MIN` or `x == INT_MAX` depending on signedness.

Comment: Why did you do `#define NDEBUG 1` instead of just `#define NDEBUG`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili — quirk.  No special reason.  Indeed, I think I’d more usually omit the `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using integer arithmetic that computes the correct result for all values in the defined range: `x` and `y` can be any `int` value with `y != 0 && !(x == INT_MIN && y == -1)`.

Other integer based solutions behave incorrectly for values too close to `INT_MIN` and/or `INT_MAX`.

```c
// simpler function if x >= 0 and y > 0
int rquotient_UU(int x, int y) {
    int quo = x / y;
    int rem = x % y;
    return quo + (rem > ((y - 1) >> 1));
}

// generic function for y != 0 and !(x == INT_MIN && y == -1)
int rquotient_SS(int x, int y) {
    int quo = x / y;
    int rem = x % y;
    if (rem == 0)
        return quo;
    // quo * y + rem = x
    if (rem > 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            return quo + (rem > (y - 1) / 2);
        } else {
            return quo - (rem > -((y + 1) / 2));
        }
    } else {
        if (y > 0) {
            return quo - (rem < -((y - 1) / 2));
        } else {
            return quo + (rem < ((y + 1) / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

These functions are only marginally slower than the ones tested by Jonathan Leffler. I expanded his test bench to include negative values and got this output on my old laptop:

```
rquotient_UU:    9.409108  (278977174548)
rquotient_SS:   12.851408  (278977174548)
rquotient_uu:    8.734572  (278977174548)
rquotient_su:    8.700956  (278977174548)
rquotient_ss:   12.079210  (278977174548)
rquotient_dd:   12.554621  (278977174548)
```

Answer (score 0):

For rounding to the nearest integer, we're only interested in the remainder if it is larger than half of the numerator. In other words; we're only interested in the decimal part if it's greater or equal to 0.5. We don't even need to know the value of the decimal part. We only need to know if it is greater or equal to 0.5. The modulo operation is expensive, so an alternative would be to multiply the numerator by 2 before doing the integer division. Or to left-shift it by 1, which is quicker, but gcc does that substitution for you.

After this division, the least-significant bit will contain the remaining 0.5. All you need to do is to add that to the result after shifting it back.

Below a code example, to make it more visual:

```
unsigned int uintdiv1(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    if (div & 1)
        return (div >> 1) + 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}
```

This version might be a bit quicker, and can be converted to a macro more easily:

```
unsigned int uintdiv2(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    div += (div & 1) << 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}
```

These examples work for unsigned integers, but you requested a solution for signed integers. That makes things a little more complicated, but not much.

If the result is negative, the default rounding already works in our favor. So we only need to test if the result is expected to be positive, and add the remaining 0.5 only if that's the case.

Again a code example, to make it more visual:

```
int intdiv1(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    if (!((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator < 0)) && (div & 1))
        return (div >> 1) + 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}
```

The really brave among us, could write it like this, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it may produce unexpected result with non-gcc compilers:

```
int intdiv2(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    div += (!((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator < 0)) && (div & 1)) << 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}
```

This algorithm could be implemented in a macro, which is more versatile, because macros are handled by the preprocessor and are type agnostic.

```
#define INTDIV(n, d)  (((((n) << 1) / (d)) + ((!(((n) < 0) ^ ((d) < 0)) && ((((n) << 1) / (d)) & 1)) ? (1 << 1) : 0)) >> 1)
```

**What you really need to be aware of, is that the implementations above do not deal with overflow errors.** If you plug in a very large number, and it is multiplied by 2, it may overflow, causing all kinds of havoc. This can be mitigated to some extend by using 64-bit arithmetic when using the macro:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int result = INTDIV((uint64_t)n, d);
```

And finally the proof that it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


#define INTDIV(n, d)                    (((((n) << 1) / (d)) + ((!(((n) < 0) ^ ((d) < 0)) && ((((n) << 1) / (d)) & 1)) ? (1 << 1) : 0)) >> 1)


static unsigned int uintdiv1(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    if (div & 1)
        return (div >> 1) + 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}

static unsigned int uintdiv2(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    div += (div & 1) << 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}

static int intdiv1(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    if (!((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator < 0)) && (div & 1))
        return (div >> 1) + 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}

static int intdiv2(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  div;

    div = (numerator << 1) / denominator;
    div += (!((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator < 0)) && (div & 1)) << 1;

    return (div >> 1);
}

static void pruintdiv1(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  expected = roundf((float)numerator / denominator);
    unsigned int  result   = uintdiv1(numerator, denominator);

    printf("%u / %u = %u, uintdiv1(%u, %u) = %u%s\n", numerator, denominator, expected, numerator, denominator, result, (result != expected) ? " ERROR!" : "");
}

static void pruintdiv2(unsigned int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
    unsigned int  expected = roundf((float)numerator / denominator);
    unsigned int  result   = uintdiv2(numerator, denominator);

    printf("%u / %u = %u, uintdiv2(%u, %u) = %u%s\n", numerator, denominator, expected, numerator, denominator, result, (result != expected) ? " ERROR!" : "");
}

static void printdiv1(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  expected = roundf((float)numerator / denominator);
    int  result   = intdiv1(numerator, denominator);

    printf("%d / %d = %d, intdiv1(%d, %d) = %d%s\n", numerator, denominator, expected, numerator, denominator, result, (result != expected) ? " ERROR!" : "");
}

static void printdiv2(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  expected = roundf((float)numerator / denominator);
    int  result   = intdiv2(numerator, denominator);

    printf("%d / %d = %d, intdiv2(%d, %d) = %d%s\n", numerator, denominator, expected, numerator, denominator, result, (result != expected) ? " ERROR!" : "");
}

static void prINTDIV(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int  expected = roundf((float)numerator / denominator);
    int  result   = INTDIV(numerator, denominator);

    printf("%d / %d = %d, INTDIV(%d, %d) = %d%s\n", numerator, denominator, expected, numerator, denominator, result, (result != expected) ? " ERROR!" : "");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pruintdiv1(57, 4);
    pruintdiv1(58, 4);
    pruintdiv1(59, 4);
    pruintdiv1(60, 4);
    pruintdiv1(61, 4);
    pruintdiv1(62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    pruintdiv2(57, 4);
    pruintdiv2(58, 4);
    pruintdiv2(59, 4);
    pruintdiv2(60, 4);
    pruintdiv2(61, 4);
    pruintdiv2(62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv1(57, 4);
    printdiv1(58, 4);
    printdiv1(59, 4);
    printdiv1(60, 4);
    printdiv1(61, 4);
    printdiv1(62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv1(-57, 4);
    printdiv1(-58, 4);
    printdiv1(-59, 4);
    printdiv1(-60, 4);
    printdiv1(-61, 4);
    printdiv1(-62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv1(57, -4);
    printdiv1(58, -4);
    printdiv1(59, -4);
    printdiv1(60, -4);
    printdiv1(61, -4);
    printdiv1(62, -4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv1(-57, -4);
    printdiv1(-58, -4);
    printdiv1(-59, -4);
    printdiv1(-60, -4);
    printdiv1(-61, -4);
    printdiv1(-62, -4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv2(57, 4);
    printdiv2(58, 4);
    printdiv2(59, 4);
    printdiv2(60, 4);
    printdiv2(61, 4);
    printdiv2(62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv2(-57, 4);
    printdiv2(-58, 4);
    printdiv2(-59, 4);
    printdiv2(-60, 4);
    printdiv2(-61, 4);
    printdiv2(-62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv2(57, -4);
    printdiv2(58, -4);
    printdiv2(59, -4);
    printdiv2(60, -4);
    printdiv2(61, -4);
    printdiv2(62, -4);
    printf("\n");
    printdiv2(-57, -4);
    printdiv2(-58, -4);
    printdiv2(-59, -4);
    printdiv2(-60, -4);
    printdiv2(-61, -4);
    printdiv2(-62, -4);
    printf("\n");
    prINTDIV(57, 4);
    prINTDIV(58, 4);
    prINTDIV(59, 4);
    prINTDIV(60, 4);
    prINTDIV(61, 4);
    prINTDIV(62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    prINTDIV(-57, 4);
    prINTDIV(-58, 4);
    prINTDIV(-59, 4);
    prINTDIV(-60, 4);
    prINTDIV(-61, 4);
    prINTDIV(-62, 4);
    printf("\n");
    prINTDIV(57, -4);
    prINTDIV(58, -4);
    prINTDIV(59, -4);
    prINTDIV(60, -4);
    prINTDIV(61, -4);
    prINTDIV(62, -4);
    printf("\n");
    prINTDIV(-57, -4);
    prINTDIV(-58, -4);
    prINTDIV(-59, -4);
    prINTDIV(-60, -4);
    prINTDIV(-61, -4);
    prINTDIV(-62, -4);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Build with:

```
$ gcc intdiv.c -Wall -pedantic -lm -o intdiv
```

And let her rip:

```
robert@prodesk:~/src/test/intdiv$ ./intdiv 
57 / 4 = 14, uintdiv1(57, 4) = 14
58 / 4 = 15, uintdiv1(58, 4) = 15
59 / 4 = 15, uintdiv1(59, 4) = 15
60 / 4 = 15, uintdiv1(60, 4) = 15
61 / 4 = 15, uintdiv1(61, 4) = 15
62 / 4 = 16, uintdiv1(62, 4) = 16

57 / 4 = 14, uintdiv2(57, 4) = 14
58 / 4 = 15, uintdiv2(58, 4) = 15
59 / 4 = 15, uintdiv2(59, 4) = 15
60 / 4 = 15, uintdiv2(60, 4) = 15
61 / 4 = 15, uintdiv2(61, 4) = 15
62 / 4 = 16, uintdiv2(62, 4) = 16

57 / 4 = 14, intdiv1(57, 4) = 14
58 / 4 = 15, intdiv1(58, 4) = 15
59 / 4 = 15, intdiv1(59, 4) = 15
60 / 4 = 15, intdiv1(60, 4) = 15
61 / 4 = 15, intdiv1(61, 4) = 15
62 / 4 = 16, intdiv1(62, 4) = 16

-57 / 4 = -14, intdiv1(-57, 4) = -14
-58 / 4 = -15, intdiv1(-58, 4) = -15
-59 / 4 = -15, intdiv1(-59, 4) = -15
-60 / 4 = -15, intdiv1(-60, 4) = -15
-61 / 4 = -15, intdiv1(-61, 4) = -15
-62 / 4 = -16, intdiv1(-62, 4) = -16

57 / -4 = -14, intdiv1(57, -4) = -14
58 / -4 = -15, intdiv1(58, -4) = -15
59 / -4 = -15, intdiv1(59, -4) = -15
60 / -4 = -15, intdiv1(60, -4) = -15
61 / -4 = -15, intdiv1(61, -4) = -15
62 / -4 = -16, intdiv1(62, -4) = -16

-57 / -4 = 14, intdiv1(-57, -4) = 14
-58 / -4 = 15, intdiv1(-58, -4) = 15
-59 / -4 = 15, intdiv1(-59, -4) = 15
-60 / -4 = 15, intdiv1(-60, -4) = 15
-61 / -4 = 15, intdiv1(-61, -4) = 15
-62 / -4 = 16, intdiv1(-62, -4) = 16

57 / 4 = 14, intdiv2(57, 4) = 14
58 / 4 = 15, intdiv2(58, 4) = 15
59 / 4 = 15, intdiv2(59, 4) = 15
60 / 4 = 15, intdiv2(60, 4) = 15
61 / 4 = 15, intdiv2(61, 4) = 15
62 / 4 = 16, intdiv2(62, 4) = 16

-57 / 4 = -14, intdiv2(-57, 4) = -14
-58 / 4 = -15, intdiv2(-58, 4) = -15
-59 / 4 = -15, intdiv2(-59, 4) = -15
-60 / 4 = -15, intdiv2(-60, 4) = -15
-61 / 4 = -15, intdiv2(-61, 4) = -15
-62 / 4 = -16, intdiv2(-62, 4) = -16

57 / -4 = -14, intdiv2(57, -4) = -14
58 / -4 = -15, intdiv2(58, -4) = -15
59 / -4 = -15, intdiv2(59, -4) = -15
60 / -4 = -15, intdiv2(60, -4) = -15
61 / -4 = -15, intdiv2(61, -4) = -15
62 / -4 = -16, intdiv2(62, -4) = -16

-57 / -4 = 14, intdiv2(-57, -4) = 14
-58 / -4 = 15, intdiv2(-58, -4) = 15
-59 / -4 = 15, intdiv2(-59, -4) = 15
-60 / -4 = 15, intdiv2(-60, -4) = 15
-61 / -4 = 15, intdiv2(-61, -4) = 15
-62 / -4 = 16, intdiv2(-62, -4) = 16

57 / 4 = 14, INTDIV(57, 4) = 14
58 / 4 = 15, INTDIV(58, 4) = 15
59 / 4 = 15, INTDIV(59, 4) = 15
60 / 4 = 15, INTDIV(60, 4) = 15
61 / 4 = 15, INTDIV(61, 4) = 15
62 / 4 = 16, INTDIV(62, 4) = 16

-57 / 4 = -14, INTDIV(-57, 4) = -14
-58 / 4 = -15, INTDIV(-58, 4) = -15
-59 / 4 = -15, INTDIV(-59, 4) = -15
-60 / 4 = -15, INTDIV(-60, 4) = -15
-61 / 4 = -15, INTDIV(-61, 4) = -15
-62 / 4 = -16, INTDIV(-62, 4) = -16

57 / -4 = -14, INTDIV(57, -4) = -14
58 / -4 = -15, INTDIV(58, -4) = -15
59 / -4 = -15, INTDIV(59, -4) = -15
60 / -4 = -15, INTDIV(60, -4) = -15
61 / -4 = -15, INTDIV(61, -4) = -15
62 / -4 = -16, INTDIV(62, -4) = -16

-57 / -4 = 14, INTDIV(-57, -4) = 14
-58 / -4 = 15, INTDIV(-58, -4) = 15
-59 / -4 = 15, INTDIV(-59, -4) = 15
-60 / -4 = 15, INTDIV(-60, -4) = 15
-61 / -4 = 15, INTDIV(-61, -4) = 15
-62 / -4 = 16, INTDIV(-62, -4) = 16
```